# Как сократить потребление процессорного времени chilkat http c#

Tags: c#

Собственно, использую библиотеку Chilkat http под .Net 4.6 для отправки пост и гет запросов, в многопоточном режиме. Если запустить около сотни-двух потоков, процессор грузится под завязку, хотя при использовании HttpWebRequest такая проблема не наблюдается, собственно что может вызывать такое потребление процессорного времени и как это исправить?

```
            Chilkat.Http http = new Chilkat.Http();

        http.S3Ssl = true;
        http.SslProtocol = "TLS 1.2";
        http.AllowGzip = true;
        http.AutoAddHostHeader = true;
        http.CookieDir = "memory";
        http.SaveCookies = true;
        http.SendCookies = true;
        http.FollowRedirects = true;
        http.ConnectTimeout = 60;
        http.ReadTimeout = 60;


        http.UnlockComponent("qAnhdt.CB_0738KCFKR1iW");
```

я думаю что это возможно связанно с разблокированием компонента(моя догадка), но как это проверить не имею понятия

Comment: 1) В студии есть профайлер посмотрите им что грузит проц 2) теоретически пара сотен потоков тоже может грузить 3) чем стандартный httpclient/httpwebrequest не устроил?

Comment: нету возможности работы с socks прокси, и задавать свои SslAllowedCiphers